# .net Get localized DateTime format specifiers

Tags: .net, datetime, format

It is possible in .net to get localized DateTime specifiers?

For example for Italian language:

```
d > g
dd > gg
mm > mm
hh > oo
yyyy > aaaa
```

and so on

Comment: I guess you are trying to allow users to specify the date format somehow right? well AFAIK I don't think you can, you'll have to implement it yourself (but I might be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way that you are thinking, no.  The [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) date and time format strings are themselves language-neutral.

They can be *applied* using a specific language or culture identifier, like so:

```csharp
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;                      // or your value
string format = "g";                             // whatever format you like
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");  // the culture code
string s = dt.ToString(format, culture);         // apply them both
```